# 16.04 LTS. zBook with Dreamcolor and nVidia. Disabled screen turns on after screen lock

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 16.04, xorg, multiple-monitors

I have an HP zBook with a Dream Color display and nVidia graphics. I use 
an external zDisplay. I go into the nVidia X server settings and turn off my
built in laptop display in order to only use the external monitor. This is
something I have done with Ubuntu releases ranging from version 8. In version 
16.04 LTS I experience an annoying behavior. When leaving my laptop for a 
while and returning Ubuntu shows the login screen (normal) but on BOTH 
displays, despite that I disabled the built in laptop screen. After entering 
my password BOTH displays are on and I need to once again, go into the nVidia X server settings and turn off the built in Display.